# Deploy two different java projects in different servers consuming each other

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss6.x

I have a java web project running on JBoss EAP 6.1,  they are asking me to separate the DAO and Service Layer in a new project and deploy it in a new server and the front layer in another new project and deploy it in another new server for security reasons.

Is this possible an do you know a guide or an example for doing that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a war project for the ui.  This will have the JSP files, servlets, or what ever front end stuff you are using.  If you are starting with a new project, use Spring mvc or Spring boot.
2. Create a war project for the backend.  If you are starting a new project, use Spring mvc or Spring boot.  Perhaps Spring REST as well.  This project will have handlers (a Spring term) to which you send messages from the first project.

Read this: [Spring Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/)